# How to configure 'Add Data to Profile URL' in Auth Dialog?

Tags: facebook, oauth, dialog, authentication

I'm currently configuring my Auth Dialog for my new Facebook app, however, according to the documentation here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/

It explains what happens when you configure the 'Add Data to Profile URL' i.e. it creates 'Perforated Unit' and 'Add to my timeline link', but....

It does not explain how to actually set up such a link!

How is this done?